# Using trigger in mysql to find time-in and time out from master table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

Everyone, I have a little problem here. The idea is simple. I need to extract value to child table **each time I insert** new rows into the master table.

Master table :

```
+--------+------------+-------+   
+ id     + dates      + time  +
+--------+------------+-------+
+ 101    + 2017/07/24 + 07:12 +
+ 101    + 2017/07/24 + 16:02 +
+ 102    + 2017/07/24 + 07:10 +
+ 102    + 2017/07/24 + 15:58 +
+ 103    + 2017/07/24 + 07:02 +
+ 103    + 2017/07/24 + 16:05 +
+ 101    + 2017/07/25 + 07:10 +
+ 101    + 2017/07/25 + 15:34 +
+ 102    + 2017/07/25 + 07:00 +
+ 102    + 2017/07/25 + 16:38 +
+ 103    + 2017/07/25 + 07:02 +
+ 103    + 2017/07/25 + 16:18 +
```

Then we go for the child table which triggered each time the new rows is inserted to the master table. The table should be like :

```
+--------+------------+---------+----------+   
+ id     + dates      + time_in + time_out +
+--------+------------+---------+----------+
+ 101    + 2017/07/24 + 07:12   + 16:02    +
+ 102    + 2017/07/24 + 07:10   + 15:58    +
+ 103    + 2017/07/24 + 07:02   + 16:05    +
+ 101    + 2017/07/25 + 07:10   + 15:34    +
+ 102    + 2017/07/25 + 07:00   + 16:38    +
+ 103    + 2017/07/25 + 07:02   + 16:18    +
```

Usualy, I make this **SQL** code to generate the child table :

```
INSERT INTO child_table (id, dates, time_in, time_out) 
SELECT id, dates, MIN(time) as time_in, MAX(time) as time_out FROM 
master_table GROUP BY dates, id
```

Before I realize that my codes take much longer to load the page. I think It'd be much efficient to work with trigger. Please help :)

Comment: what's issue??  you said "child table which triggered each time the new rows is inserted to the master"  you seems to already using trigger

Comment: @Ashish451 looks like OP is manually inserting the rows into child table.

Comment: @Ashish451 Triggered, I mean generate. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are doing insert manually and wanted trigger use this

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `ADD_DATA_AUTO` AFTER INSERT ON `MASTERTABLE` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN    

INSERT INTO child_table (id, dates, time_in, time_out) 
SELECT id, dates, MIN(time) as time_in, MAX(time) as time_out FROM 
master_table GROUP BY dates, id


END//
DELIMITER ;
```

what this trigger doest it it tells mysql to run insert query **AFTER INSERT** in MASTERTABLE

Comment: I need to do some modification but it works. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct using trigger is a better option compare to inserting every time you load the page.

Take a look on the tutorial [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-triggers.php). In your case you should be using AFTER INSERT Trigger which insert a new record to your child table after a new row inserted to the master table. Proceed to the part **MySQL Trigger : Example AFTER INSERT** , should give you a good idea on how to construct the trigger for your scenario. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Really appreciate it.